# patches-own a vector in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

In the patches-own section at the start, can I index one of the variables over a breed, so it's a vector rather than a single variable?

Specifically, I've got a breed called Developers (it's an ABM of house-building), and patches own a land-price, but I want them to own a different land price for each developer. Is this possible?

My failed attempt, with 2 developers, is

```
patches-own [ land-price ( n-values 2 developer ) ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved a numerous ways.

One solution can be to let the patch-variable be a list. You can't initialize it inside the patches-own block. Instead, initialize it in your setup method.

```
patches-own [land-prices]

to setup
    ca
    create-developers 10
    let initial-price 10
    ask patches [ set land-prices (count developers) initial-price]
end
```

You'll need to be careful about ordering though. For example, alot of the commands like `of` produces a list of random size. You may want to use the developer's `who` to index them.

One way to get around that is to use the table extension to create a table of who to price. You'd need to include table in your extensions and modify your setup. See: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/table.html

Consider this for the table solution, where I make use of the from-list function in tables to initialize the table:

```
patches-own [land-prices]
breed [developers developer]
extensions [table]
to setup
  ca
  create-developers 10
  let initial-price 10
  ask patches [ set land-prices table:from-list [(list who initial-price)] of developers]
end
```

Both of these are memory intensive operations. You may want to tread lightly or explain why it's necessary to store so much information.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using a raw list, for the reasons of ordering that you mention. And I think using `who` for indexing items in the list would create more problems than it would solve. Your suggestion of using `who` as a table key, however, is perfectly sensible and probably the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, using a raw...?

Comment: Sorry: a raw _list_. Fixed above.

Comment: What is `initial-price` here- is that a value from your interface (I can't get it to work)? I think for ease-of-use I'd lean towards storing the land prices in the developers- is there an argument against doing so?

Comment: initial-price is just a place holder for the initial-pricing. There is an argument against and for storing the prices in the developers; however, I think that it really depends on what type of operations the rest of the code uses (i.e. how much memory is being accessed at a time on the program's side of things). I wouldn't want to state an argument until I see more written.

Comment: Thanks both. I managed to cobble together a particular inelegant solution for 2 developers in the interim, which involved giving each patch two prices, one for each developer. I've not really used tables before, but I think they could help me in other ways, so I'll have a go.

Answer (score 2):

@mattsap's suggestion of using the `table` extension is probably the way to go, but just for the record: you might also consider using links.

The problem, in this case, is that a link can only be between a turtle and a turtle, never between turtle and a patch.

You could, however, consider making your "lands" turtles, and just put one on each patch. Here is a full example of what I mean:

```
breed [ lands land ]
breed [ developers developer ]
undirected-link-breed [ price-links price-link ]
price-links-own [ price ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape lands "square"
  create-developers 10
  ask patches [
    sprout-lands 1 [
      set color green - 3
      create-price-links-with n-of 2 developers [
        hide-link
        set price random 100
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, there might be some trade offs involved (memory being one) but conceptually, this is a very clean way to proceed.

And NetLogo makes it very easy and pleasant to work with links (much more pleasant than using the `table` extension in my opinion). The main advantage is that you can query links from both directions:

```
observer> ask one-of developers [ show [ price ] of my-price-links ]
(developer 6): [85 68 79 26 40 60 72 85 94 50 63 75 81 97 15 46 71 34 75 15 87 0 30 9 57 23 14 63 73 66 5 13 94 20 78 8 36 12 18 49 43 35 24 38 93 34 15 72 63 68 15 86 46 21 30 67 19 89 73 62 83 33 14 13 62 46 54 17 12 35 58 7 29 51 35 99 95 96 78 74 81 36 98 45 86 2 3 45 24 35 35 43 11 63 72 11 50 16 14 60 36 89 83 50 64 65 11 38 92 75 78 94 76 12 77 30 6 61 79 63 39 68 20 99 43 72 74 1 12 18 70 98 23 72 2 15 11 44 29 17 24 73 74 53 42 63 23 53 86 45 6 60 17 49 98 79 69 96 54 6 19 20 99 46 1 31 66 85 22 42 74 2 19 60 93 54 37 20 77 75 64 42 78 40 82 11 91 13 56 56 28 34 42 5 75 7 46 91 69 83 76 92 69 71 14 35 30 85 78 95 25 3 2 1 77 73 92 31 54 83 5 89 2 32 19 10 59 72 80 93 60 62 44 92 49 49]
observer> ask one-of lands [ show [ price ] of my-price-links ]
(land 997): [43 70]
```

Or you can get to the developers directly from the land (and vice versa):

```
observer> ask one-of lands [ show sort price-link-neighbors ]
(land 112): [(developer 4) (developer 5)]
```

To show the price of a specific developer for a specific land:

```
observer> ask developer 2 [ show [ price ] of price-link-with land 737 ]
(developer 2): 94
```

See the [**Links** section of the NetLogo dictionnary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#linkgroup) for all the neat things that you can do...